# db2 function to convert lower case to upper case for accented characters

Tags: sql, db2

I need to convert all the characters of a first name to upper case in a DB2 table. I was using the upper function but came across an issue dealing with accented characters. For example, I need 'é' to become 'É'. The upper function seems to ignore these accented characters. I've had no luck finding anything related to this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

DB2 has a UPPER function with locale sensitive: [Link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0052777.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-9-4-1-184&lang=en)

```
>>-UPPER--(--string-expression--,--locale-name--+---------------+--+--------------------+--)-><
                                                '-,--code-units-'  '-,--+-CODEUNITS16-+-'      
                                                                        +-CODEUNITS32-+        
                                                                        '-OCTETS------'
```

If that does not work for you, you can create your own function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPPER_CASE(
  IN STRING VARCHAR(256)
  ) RETURN VARCHAR(256)
 UPPER_CASE: BEGIN
  -- Replaces á with Á
  SET STRING = REPLACE (STRING, u&'\00e1', u&'\00c1');
  -- Replaces é with É
  SET STRING = REPLACE (STRING, u&'\00e9', u&'\00c9');
  -- ...
  RETURN STRING;
 END UPPER_CASE @
```

I wrote an article in my personal blog about sorting with different collating sequence. That [article](http://angocadb2.blogspot.fr/2014/08/db2-collating-sequence-for-order-by.html) could help you to write your function.

Comment: [`TRANSLATE(...)` can be used to replace multiple characters at a time](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000862.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-164&lang=en).  I'd also probably back this with a table, to make additions easier.